# How can I divide COUNT by 6?

Tags: mysql

So, probably spelled my question wrong, anyway.
I'm trying to run a test scenario where some values are duplicated, so they should be 6 but if duplicated they are 12 or 18 and so on,

Currently I'm finding them by
    having COUNT(*) > 6

but I also want to make sure that the return result would be only those that can be divided by 6 , like 12/6, 18/6 would be returned, but something like 15/6 would not, so I suppose its 'whole' numbers - integer.

```
select rr.review_id
from review_rating rr
inner join review rw on 
rr.review_id = rw.id
group by review_id
having COUNT(*) > 6
```

So, I only want to filter the results whose count can be divided by 6 and the result would be an integer/whole number.

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) MOD 6 = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select rr.review_id
from review_rating rr
inner join review rw on rr.review_id = rw.id
group by review_id
having MOD(COUNT(*),6)=0
```

Comment: Hey, this worked, follow up question - what do I change the 0 to if I want to list only those that cant be divided by 6

Comment: @Ruthock Simply remove compare and use `... HAVING MOD(COUNT(*),6) ;`.

Comment: @Akina I think I got it working with MOD(COUNT(*),6) = 1 in order to list only the results that are not dividable by 6. I dont really understand what you meant by removing compare?

Comment: `WHERE MOD(COUNT(*),6) = 1` will give true for 1,7,13, ... and false for 0,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,... - i.e. not ALL values which cannot be divided by 6 without reminder will be returned. Whereas `WHERE MOD(COUNT(*),6)` returns true for all values values which cannot be divided by 6 without reminder. Any non-zero value (obtained as a reminder) is treated as true.

Comment: Thank you, I understood it now. However, how do I keep the Count(*) > 6 and still have the mod count?

Also, this is what I get :
"ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type bigint"

Comment: Wouldn't MOD(COUNT(*),6) != 0 do the trick?